# Grep logs from the last hour

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I am trying to grep logs that happened in the last hour, time format is like this:
**2020-11-01 18:46:56**.036

I tried to run this:

```
grep "^$(date -d -1 hour +'%Y-%m-%d %H')" postgresql-Mon.log | tail -n 100
```

but that doesn't work. Also how do I use the tail command without -n? I want to grep from bottom to top but to get all the logs from the last hour not only 100.

Help please :>

I know there are other ways doing it but I need it with grep command

Comment: `tail -100` is tail without `n`

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H" -d '1 hour ago')"
```

must work

```
[root@dell-shatov-dk ~]# cat ./test.log 
2020-11-02 07:21:10.104 t1
2020-11-02 08:21:10.104 t2
2020-11-02 09:21:10.104 t3
2020-11-02 10:21:10.104 t4
2020-11-02 11:21:10.104 t5
[root@dell-shatov-dk ~]# grep "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H" -d '1 hour ago')" test.log
2020-11-02 11:21:10.104 t5
```

Comment: `[root@pg67 log]# cat test.log
2020-11-02 07:21:10.104
2020-11-02 08:21:10.104
2020-11-02 09:21:10.104
2020-11-02 10:21:10.104

You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
[root@pg67 log]# grep $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H" -d '1 hour ago') test.log
grep: 07: No such file or directory
test.log:2020-11-02 07:21:10.104
test.log:2020-11-02 08:21:10.104
test.log:2020-11-02 09:21:10.104
test.log:2020-11-02 10:21:10.104
[root@pg67 log]# date
Mon Nov  2 08:55:02 UTC 2020
 `

Comment: `grep "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H" -d '1 hour ago')" test.log`, sorry, missing quotes

Comment: This will fail if the grepped date is not in the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H" -d '1 hour ago')" test.log
```